# how to get the contents of a cluster from Spectral Biclustering scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am using **Spectral Biclustering** algorithm and I want to know which values are grouped together. First I want to know if  there is a way to get the contents of each cluster?
and second, is it possible to add labels to the graph?

the code is similar to this :

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_checkerboard
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralBiclustering
from sklearn.metrics import consensus_score


n_clusters = (4, 3)
data, rows, columns = make_checkerboard(
    shape=(300, 300), n_clusters=n_clusters, noise=10, shuffle=False, random_state=0
)

plt.matshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.title("Original dataset")

# shuffle clusters
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
row_idx = rng.permutation(data.shape[0])
col_idx = rng.permutation(data.shape[1])
data = data[row_idx][:, col_idx]

plt.matshow(data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.title("Shuffled dataset")

model = SpectralBiclustering(n_clusters=n_clusters, method="log", random_state=0)
model.fit(data)
score = consensus_score(model.biclusters_, (rows[:, row_idx], columns[:, col_idx]))

print("consensus score: {:.1f}".format(score))

fit_data = data[np.argsort(model.row_labels_)]
fit_data = fit_data[:, np.argsort(model.column_labels_)]

plt.matshow(fit_data, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.title("After biclustering; rearranged to show biclusters")

plt.matshow(
    np.outer(np.sort(model.row_labels_) + 1, np.sort(model.column_labels_) + 1),
    cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
)
plt.title("Checkerboard structure of rearranged data")

plt.show()
```